# sendmail Google Apps Script attachment multiple files

Tags: google-apps-script, sendmail

I use Google Apps Script for send email with on doc attachment (anexo.doc)
I need to send 2 attachment in same email (anexo.doc and anexo2.doc)

How i do this?
My actually code is:

```
    file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('anexo.doc');

    if (file.hasNext()) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(tomail, subject, msg, {
      attachments: [file.next().getAs('application/msword')],
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
      }
    )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('anexo.doc');
file2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('anexo2.doc');

if (file.hasNext() && file2.hasNext()) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(tomail, subject, msg, {
    attachments: [
      file.next().getAs('application/msword'),
      file2.next().getAs('application/msword')],
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
   }
 )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface by saying that I didn't add the loop for creating the array holding the files. however here is my twist to the code by @CaringDev.

Instead getting the files in the attachment section you can also store them in an array and choose them this way.

```
 //code for the loop//
 var files = [];
    try {
       var rangefile = ss.getRange("a2:a3").getValues();
        //Logger.log(rangefile); 
       let i = 0;
       rangefile.forEach((fileIt) => {
       let drivefile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(rangefile[i]).next();
         files.push(drivefile);
        
       i=i+1;
       
       });
       
     }
    
    catch (error) {
      Browser.msgBox('File not in google drive.');
      throw new Error( "File not in google drive.");
    }
     //code to send email
         MailApp.sendEmail(
                    email, 
                    subject, 
                    message,
                    attachments: [
                      files[0],
                      files[1],
                      files[2]
                                 ],
                    name: 'Burton Griffin',} );
```